# How to get linqpad to update columns

Tags: c#, sql, linqpad

I am trying to do the equivalent of an SQL UPDATE with C# statements in linqpad but the data doesn't change and I'm not sure to even debug it further to figure out why. The User table is pretty standard with just a string to store Sid.

```
var usersWithSid = from u in Users where u.Sid != null select u;
foreach(var u in usersWithSid) {
    u.Sid = "S-1-5-21-3812666658-2998621725-2245962016-6618";
}
SubmitChanges();
usersWithSid.Dump();
```

Most of the examples I have found seem to only update one record at a time. Why doesn't this work?

Comment: This exact thing works fine for me. I'd suspect something screwy on your DB column definition (you didn't specify what kind of string the column is- perhaps something fixed-length or off row?). Mine is a varchar(200), and the update works exactly as expected.

Comment: Mine is an NVarchar(100)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you have a primary key defined on the table? The updates will silently fail if you don't.

Comment: Nailed by that once or twice myself. Glad it was easy.

Comment: LinqPad actually warns you when you generate the DataContext, but the warning is at the bottom of the table list- easy to miss.

Comment: The silent failures are annoying.